# Bootstrap-DatePicker set open-date without setting default

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to set the open-to date in a the bootstrap-datepicker in AngularJS without filling a field with the a set defaultdate value. I only want to change the date which the datepicker opens to. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular ui bootstrap datepicker is bound to a model.  You need to set the ng-model statement to the date you want it to open to.  So if the datepicker is bound to

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

but you want it to open 10/10/2010 instead, you can change the model to

```
$scope.date = new Date(2010, 10, 10);
```

If you want to change the default behavior and not have it bound to a model that would involve changing the actual code of the angular ui bootstrap datepicker which is entirely possible but it's easier to just change the value it is bound to.